# Jersey - JSON marshall only specific fields

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

My REST service returns following JSON

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "id" : 10
}
```

Can I use Jersey to marshall it into following Bean:

```
public class User{
    private String name;
    //getter & setter
}
```

I wanted to do this with following code but it doesn't work

```
WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
User user = webResource.get(User.class);
```

Is this even possible or I have to implement full JSON structure in Java Beans to get it work?

I know that I can parse this JSON with Jackson and any other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Jackson, easiest way is to configure ObjectMapper like so:

```
 objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, 
false);
```

Check this sample provider

```
package com.company.rest.jersey;
@Provider
@Component
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class JacksonMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
   ObjectMapper mapper;

   public JacksonMapperProvider(){
       mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       mapper.configure(Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

       // Serialize dates using ISO8601 format
       // Jackson uses timestamps by default, so use StdDateFormat to get ISO8601
       mapper.getSerializationConfig().setDateFormat(new StdDateFormat());

       // Deserialize dates using ISO8601 format
       // MilliDateFormat simply adds milliseconds to string if missing so it will parse
       mapper.getDeserializationConfig().setDateFormat(new MilliDateFormat());

       // Prevent exceptions from being thrown for unknown properties
       mapper.configure(
              DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,false);
   }

   @Override
   public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> aClass) {
       return mapper;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Jackson :
You have two options:

1. Jackson works on setters-getters of fields. So, you can just remove getter of field which you want to omit in JSON. ( If you don't need getter at other place.)
2. Or, you can use the `@JsonIgnore` [annotation of Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations) on getter method of that field and you see there in no such key-value pair in resulted JSON.

   ```
   @JsonIgnore
   public int getSecurityCode(){
      return securityCode;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In your bean, add the annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` at the class level and it should skip the id property in the JSON since it's not present in the bean.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class User{
    private String name;
    //getter & setter
}
```

(See http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations for details)